# Is it not possible to pipe output in Fabric tasks?

Tags: python-2.7, pipe, fabric

I'm using Fabric 1.10 for my project. For one of the tasks, I need to display a list of files present locally but not yet uploaded to the remote server. For this I use rsync.

```
rsync -avun <local-directory> <remote-server>
```

This works fine but it also displays a few summary lines and unwanted output, so I try to grep the results. However, this causes an error.

```
rsync -avun <local-directory> <remote-server> | egrep "(\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.ico|\.gif)"
Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1)...
```

Is it not possible to pipe output in Fabric commands?

Comment: Is that the entire command that you are sending to fabric? I can pipe input to fabric pretty trivially ```fab ls:"`ls -lah | awk '{print $9}' | tail -n3`"```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've mixed up, or fabric is conflicting with, your quotes. Try and use `"""`'s to surround your commands and perhaps single quotes on the egrep.